# Edit URL in address bar when title matches in Safari

Tags: safari

In Safari 6.1, under Mac OS 10.8, if I type a text in the address bar that matches the *title* of a page I have previously visited, that page is listed below. I select it and would then like to slightly edit the related URL. Instead, it only lets me editing the page title, and when pressing enter it performs a web search with the edited title. How can I change this behaviour?

This still applies in Safari 10.0 under macOS 10.11.6.  Pressing the right arrow key after the page *title* matches only takes you to the end of the page title.  The URL is displayed to the right of the cursor, but does not appear to be editable.

Here is a screenshot of a matched page *title*, before pressing the right arrow key:

[image]

Here is after pressing the right arrow key.  Note that further presses of the right arrow key do not affect anything.

[image]

Comment: That is odd behaviour. I cannot replicate it on my side. Idk if it's a safari thing.

Comment: You can try what is suggested to do [here](https://www.macissues.com/2015/06/22/how-to-fully-reset-safari-on-your-mac/) if you think that the issue you are facing is not a normal behavior of Safari 6.1.

Comment: I would like to encourage would-be answer providers to read this question very carefully. This behavior is odd, but is how Safari has behaved for years, now. (It's still true in Tech Preview 12.0 r58.)

This isn't a "bug" or a user that is missing something, it's a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might simply be: You can't.

Whether or no this is desirable could be debated, but having worked on a couple of these things in Mozilla/Firefox days, I think it is clear that someone (aka Apple) would create a browser location opener-thingie to do it this way.

Here's why I think this is Safari expected behavior:

The match you are looking is a match to a Bookmarks and History via the Title. The URL is being provided for your convenience (or if you come from a certain period of browser design and/or security orientation, its to mitigate more obvious versions of URL spoofing). It isn't trying to present TITLE PLUS URL... because if it were a mult-mode search /bookmarks+history / location interface, that would not make any sense. (You could argue it *could support* this, but that's yet-another input syntax, and a whole other round of feature development...)

The URL is not mean to be editable text in this context.

I do think there is a bug which could be either:

The auto-completion shouldn't be implied with a normal selection color, because you can't trigger completion to make the editable text appear in the location field. (Nor does cut and paste operate correctly on this string).

Answer (score -1):

This may only apply to recent OS X & Safari; I can't test back to 10.8
This is using Safari 10.0.2 on El Capitan 10.11.6

Currently, you can do it by hitting the right arrow, which will take you to the end of the auto-filled line, from where you can edit as you wish

examples...

I type `map`

[image]

Right arrow

[image]

Then delete a few letters with backspace & type my new alternative

[image]

Comment: In your example, what you type matches both the URL and the page title. Safari chose to match to the URL. It therefore does not answer the question.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you mean. Editing your question to clarify might be useful.

Comment: I found this same behavior.  I edited the question to clarify and add screenshots.

Comment: Safari 10.1 (on macOS 10.11.6 and 10.12.4) has the page title given in the small blue text and the URL in editable black, which is reversed from your screenshots and sounds like the behavior you desire.

Comment: After the edit - best guess is 'you cannot do that'. You are in effect typing a search, not a URL - all you can edit is the search.

Comment: This only work for Top Hits, which are URLs themselves. If you select a bookmark or history suggestion the title is edited, not the URL (which is completely useless as this just searches for the title)

Comment: These comments have solved the problem for me.  When I see that I'm getting a page title result, I can also see enough of the URL that I can change what I am typing and instead I type something that was in the URL and not in the title.  I can then scroll through the suggestions and they are resolving as URL instead of as text, so I can also edit them.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

> Command (⌘) + Right Arrow (→)

You'll reach the end of the URL then you can easily edit it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me on the latest stable macOS and Safari pair.

Comment: This simply goes to the end of the auto-completed title. Read the question carefully, please.