# Change url on safari search

Tags: safari, search, url

I'm trying to move from chrome to safari, but there is something which I'm not able to do so far.

I work with Jira, and when I try to browse a ticket for a known project, I can't edit the url to browse a specific ticket

[image]

For example this ticket, If I want to go browse **VSGN-146**, and previously I was working on VSGN-145 (known project), on Chrome I start typing "vsgn" and then I move to the end of the url and I can change the 5 for a 6.

If I try to do that in safari, the end of the line is "... - JIRA"
[image]

So the question is, is there a way to edit the url instead of the site description on safari? Btw, I'm using the version 10.1.1

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135270/55487

Answer (score 1):

To show the full URL in what Safari calls the *'Smart Search Field',* make sure the following is set in **Preferences**:

- Go to Safari > Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
- Select the **Advanced** tab
- Check the box "Smart Search Field: [✓] Show full website address"

Now you can edit the full URL by hand.

[image: Smart Search Field Option]

[image: Smart Search Field]

[image: Editing URL in Smart Search Field]

---

### EDIT:

Notice how the URL is now displayed with first before the title?  Just the opposite of the OP's screenshot.  Now typing the right arrow <kbd>►</kbd> will go to the end of the URL not the title as the URL is first.  (The URL and the Title are now swapped)

[image: Show full site]

Comment: Hi bjbk, thank you for the answer, but that will only work if I am in the same domain. Indeed, it works event without the "Show full website address".

Comment: Works for me from the home page.  Maybe I'm missing something in your question.  Updated answer with another screenshot.  Cheers